# Color nodes in Networkx Graph based on specific values

Tags: networkx

I have looked a bit into the `node_color` keyword parameter of the `nx.draw()` method. Here are two different graphs colored using `node_colors`.

[`node_colors = [.5,.5,0.,1.]`. Colors appear as expected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YjU6g.png)

[`node_colors = [.9,1.,1.,1.]`. Colors do not appear as expected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YevIH.png)

In the second image, I would expect the color of node 1 to be almost as dark. I assume what is happening is the colormap is getting scaled from the minimum value to the maximum value. For the first example, that's fine, but how can I set the colormap to be scaled from: 0=white, 1=blue every time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct about the cause of the problem.  To fix it, you need to define `vmin` and `vmax`.

I believe

```
nx.draw(G, node_color=[0.9,1.,1.,1.], vmin=0, vmax=1)
```

will do what you're after (I would need to know what colormap you're using to be sure).

For edges, there are similar parameters: `edge_vmin` and `edge_vmax`.